# Android - Retrofit - Query - Yahoo Weather

Tags: android, retrofit, yahoo, weather

I'm trying to request the current weather to Yahoo using Retrofit.
I'm facing an issue when trying to pass the city. I understand that I have to use @Query

Yahoo queries are a bit complex and I'm not sure how to proceed.
Here is my code

```
@GET("yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20**text%3D%22brussels%2C%20be%22)%20and%20u%3D%27c%27&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
```

In this complex query, I need to update city parameter from 
**text%3D%22brussels%2C%20be** to **text%3D%paris%2C%20fr** for instance.

Any help would be highly appreciated;

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

```
@GET("yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20**text%3D%22{location}%2C%20be%22)%20and%20u%3D%27c%27&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
Call<response> groupList(@Path("location") String location);
```

If i understand your question correctly, this should work.

Comment: Thank you Tim. So I in my Activity, I need to pass the city variable, but this is where I'm stuck. If I pass it that way: WeatherAPI.Factory.getmWeatherAPI().getWeather(city).enqueue(new Callback<Weather> - It is said that I must use a query :-/     Here is the message: must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.